# Using JQ to filter the keys that have a boolean equal to true

Tags: json, jq

I have this JSON file:

```
{
   "books":{
      "book-name-1":{
         "path":"management/business",
         "availability": true,
         "vars":{
            "author":"John",
            "year":"2005"
         }
      },
      "book-name-2":{
         "path":"engineering/computing",
         "availability": false,
         "vars":{
            "author":"Rick",
            "year":"2010"
         }
      },
      "book-name-3":{
         "path":"finance/general",
         "vars":{
            "author":"Joe",
            "year":"2020"
         }
      },
      "book-name-4":{
         "path":"medicine/general",
         "availability": true,
         "vars":{
            "author":"Stacy",
            "year":"2018"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and I can't manage to filter it in such a way that I can get the names of the books that "availability" is equal to true.

Note for example that book-name-3 does not have that variable and book-name-2 has it set to false.

So, the output I expect to get after filtering is:

```
book-name-1,
book-name-4
```

How could I make it possible using jq?

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to reduce the items to those matching the criteria, and then output the key names:

```sh
jq -r '.books | .[] |= select(.availability) | keys_unsorted[]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CC9Brk4Lv7)

Another one could be using `to_entries` and work with `.key` and `.value`:

```sh
jq -r '.books | to_entries[] | select(.value.availability).key'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cxnmYmvbXM)

Output in both cases:

```json
book-name-1
book-name-4
```

To also feature the commas, you could leave it as array, and use a `join(",\n")` to combine:

```json
book-name-1,
book-name-4
```